# Why does the $\Lambda\mathrm{CDM}$ model end up a cold de Sitter space?

Tags: cosmological-inflation, unruh-effect

If space-time is expanding at $a(t)=e^{Ht}$, you plug acceleration into the Hawking-Unruh temperature equation, solve for time, and get the cosmic horizon at the Planck temperature within about $4.4 \times 10^{27}$ years.

Is this thinking wrong?

In addition, as a curiosity - for a da/dt>0 universe, the vacuum state will become exponentially energetic.. can that vacuum be energetic enough to create a black hole in and of itself?

If so, this would create a problem in my mind - as for da/dt>0, the cosmic event horizon is continuously shrinking, yet a constant increase in vacuum energy would create black holes with an ever increasing event horizon (if black holes do start forming at every "point" within space-time due to enormous vacuum energy).

If you are still following me, does this mean a new, high energy equilibrium gets reached, where the force of gravity exactly cancels out the force of dark energy at every point of space time?

Comment: Remember that physical densities are not the same as coordinate densities, physical densities are $\sim a^{-3}$ times the coordinate ones. Similarly, the horizon and the physical distance to it also grow. De-Sitter is funny because there you loose the preferred comoving time and temperature is not unique for all observer-families. However, the temperature of the horizon in de-Sitter is going to be roughly constant and at about $\approx C H$ with $C$ some constant for the most natural observers. (Unruh formula *does not* apply, how could it even?)

Comment: Ok, but if the cosmic event horizon is shrinking, using the parallel analogy of a black hole (the Hawking radiation equation is identical), the temperature of the black hole is inversely proportional to its mass, or energy.. so smaller event horizons equal higher radiation temperatures. Why wouldn't this be the case for Unruh radiation and a shrinking cosmological event horizon?

Comment: How did you come to the conclusion that the horizon is shrinking? For one family of observers it is expanding, for another one it may be static (e.g. in [spherical coordinates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Sitter%E2%80%93Schwarzschild_metric)). Either way, no observer will ever reach it and the luminous distance to it is infinite. As stated, the temperature you obtain will depend on the *non-unique* choice of homogeneous isotropic observers.

Comment: But the axiom of inflation is surely as it approaches the limit of infinity, all matter is identically cold at 0K. A 0 energy universe.